# Is it possible to get the APEC Business Travel Card as a Canadian?

Tags: canada, visa

Is it possible to get the APEC Business Travel Card as a Canadian living in Asia?

Comment: To clarify, what are you counting as where you're living in Asia? Eg Russia, India, Thailand, Japan...?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's only possible if you are a permanent resident in Hong Kong (and then it doesn't matter that Canada is a member of APEC, UK citizens and others can get one too). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEC_Business_Travel_Card), Canada does not issue cards yet and I think other members only issue them to citizens.

Comment: Ah yes, I think you're right. My Canadian friend has the card but he is also permanent resident of HK.

Comment: Yes, Canada is only a partial member currently, and is not issuing the cards yet. I've been told this year or next, but i'm not holding my breath.